# C++ read /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate encountered permission denied

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux, fstream, beagleboneblack

I have to read the status of the ethernet interface in embedded linux using C++
I attempt to open and read the file `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate`, but i observed that fail() member function always returns true and the errno is permission denied.
My application permission indicator is 755, i also tried set it 777, but the error is still there.

Below is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   

    std::string word, filename;
    std::fstream ethfile;
    ethfile.open("/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate");

    if (ethfile.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    ethfile>>word;
    std::cout<<"word is"<<word<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Additional info: this is yocto on beaglebone.

Comment: Since you've already checked regular permissions, the next suspect would be SELinux, i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot open this particular file for writing no matter what your permissions are.

You need to use `ifstream` rather than `fstream`, or specify an open mode that does not include writing.